# A simple CSS margin or padding not working in Internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I created this css code for my website menu, it ads bullets between each menu link:
CSS:

```
.main-nav>li:after{
content:'\2022';
    margin-bottom:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
color: #ac3834;
}

.main-nav>li:last-child:after{ 
content: none;
}
```

Works great on firefox but on internet explorer this css code is simply ignored !
I tested a reset css code with margins 0 and an if statement with php to load a different style for IE but still the same.
IE simply ignore it and when i check the output code with webmaster tools
the css on IE is striketrough what does that mean btw ?

Here is the working menu with the bullets [testing website](http://lariad.pctek.fr)

Here is a picture of the IE11 weird bad behavior bug 
http://i63.tinypic.com/2n1e341.png

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: which version of IE are you seeing in . As older versions do not support modern properties of css.

Comment: I have this css problem on IE 11

Comment: The bullets appear on IE but above the menu links, seems a margin or padding problem, i tried both but with no result !

Comment: sry dude i don't know first time i aks help here, thought it would help to get more views yes, but it seems this community is very active, i'm impressed !

Comment: Share a working example or fiddle.

Comment: Here is working menu with the bullets [link](http://lariad.pctek.fr) testing website

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "bullet" is created by a glyphicon.

Unfortunately Glyphicons wont always work on IE.

IE normally has a setting to restrict font download. This is enabled by group policy and cannot be changed on standard workstations.

Se this article for further explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, interesting to know, but the glyphicon (2022) i use appear on IE, the problem is the css margin not working, or something else i don't understand. see for yourself [link](http://lariad.pctek.fr)

Comment: It works well for me on IE 11. Mabye you have to clear your cache?

Comment: Strange, i did empty cache of everything browsers, windows, and i don't use a cache system on the website but for me the bullets shows outside and above the menu in IE 11. This is weird

Answer (score 0):

1. there are specific ways for css to be build op for every IE version, so maybe u want to look that up. and if its striketrough it practicaly means that IE doesnt know what to do with the code.
2. and i dont know if this is a legit fix or not but some people in my class found a script online that converts the css so that the css can be used on IE 11 so u can try to look that up to. (correct me if im wrong on the second option)

Comment: Yes i'm aware that IE needs an other css, that's why i asked for help, i tried with an php function to detect IE browser and apply an other css style, but still the same, is ignored:

Comment: oh ok. so you have tried to look up a specific IE 11 css file and use that code instead?

Comment: I mean what is the particularity of this little css code to not work on IE, is this so special ??? i mean come on

Comment: i used this <!--[if IE]>.main-nav>li:after{
content:'\2022';
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
color: #ac3834;
}

.main-nav>li:last-child:after{ 
content: none;
}<![endif]-->

Comment: well i agree with you on the "is this so special" it is kind of @#$ that IE needs to be special about everything. but the problem is that chrome and firefox update automatically when theres new content or ways to do things in css. IE does not have this. so it always needs a push to understand things